# html span tag assembl

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a lot span in my html and I want to get some span tags and make them on same like. this is my html code

```html
<div>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>mike</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>how are you</span>
</div>
```

the output is

```
hello

mike

how are you
```

Now my question is it possible to call some span tags and make them on the same line like

```
hello mike how are you
```

Comment: what **CSS** have you tried thus far?

Comment: @treyBake am just asking is it possible. i never tried any css

Comment: Put them all in the same `div`. They don't need individual divs wrapping them.

Comment: make the divs inline or inline-block, but as others have said, fixing your markup would be the best way

Comment: There are several questions? Can you change the HTML? If yes, will you do? What is the context around your HTML? It might be important. If no HTML change allowed, which do you prefer? Changing the DOM with JavaScript or changing the appearance only with CSS? Do you have a CSS right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2terosfa/1)

Can be done in different ways as you can see here

```css
.inline div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.float div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <div>
  <span>hello</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>mike</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>how are you</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="float">
  <div>
  <span>hello</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>mike</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>how are you</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this was helpful

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` by default is a block element. Spans are `inline` elements. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) for more information

So

```
<div>
<span>hello</span>
<span>mike</span>
<span>how are you</span>
</div>
```

would achieve what you want.

Additionally, you could make the div's be `inline-block`, you could use `flexbox`, you could set less than 100% width on the divs, etc

Comment: upvote for actually explaining the issue^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in one div

Like this:

```html
   <div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>mike</span>
    <span>how are you</span>
   </div>
```